# ¿Traducción de "take-home message"?

Tags: traducción

Linguée.com me sugirió *moraleja, conclusión* y *mensaje final* para "take-home message." No me satisface ninguna de esas opciones.

"Take-home message" me da la idea de una conclusión *práctica*.  Además, la combinación de palabras tiene algo de especial.

¿Existe otra opción más grata?  (Se permite inventar algo....)

**Edit 5/3**:

Los ejemplos que puso @Charlie me animaron a inventar algo.  Estoy imaginando una charla:

> ¿Cuál es el **chiste** de todo esto?  Que las técnicas clásicas de (cierto campo científico) se pueden usar, con algunos ajustes, para resolver nuevos problemas de (cierto sub-campo científico).

Pero en conversación me gusta más la frase que encontró de 1997:

**El mensaje para llevar a casa**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo usaría alguna de estas variantes, suponiendo que la dice al final de su exposición alguien que está dando una charla:

- La idea con la que os tenéis que quedar.
- El concepto/mensaje que os tenéis que llevar a casa.
- Lo que tiene que quedar claro.

Ejemplo:

> *Una idea tiene que quedar muy clara: es preferible y mucho más beneficioso caminar todos los días una hora que en un solo día caminar 5 horas.*
>
> Luis Gutiérrez Serantes, "365 días para vivir con salud", 2002 (España).

Otro que traduce literalmente la propuesta en inglés:

> *El mensaje para llevar a casa es que hay mucha más flexibilidad en nuestro linaje que la que habíamos imaginado.*
>
> El Tiempo, 28/04/1997 : Tiempo de Ciencia (Colombia).

Si prefieres algo más breve y conciso, yo usaría *quid*:

> **[quid](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UpHbqdL)**
>
> Del lat. *quid* 'qué', 'por qué'.
>
> 1. m. Esencia, punto más importante o porqué de una cosa.

Ejemplo novelesco que ilustra cómo resumir en pocas palabras lo más importante de algo de lo que se ha hablado (o se conoce) previamente, usando *quid*:

> *—Método, entrenamiento y concentración, ese es el quid.*
>
> María Manuela Reina, "Alta seducción", 1989 (España).

Y personalmente no descartaría *moraleja* tan rápido:

> **[moraleja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pm5dKdp)**
>
> De *moral<sup>1</sup>* y *-eja*.
>
> 1. f. Lección o enseñanza que se deduce de un cuento, fábula, ejemplo, anécdota, etc.

No puedo resistirme a exponer el siguiente ejemplo que acabo de encontrar en el CREA:

> *Cuento corto: este poderoso Mew2 conoce el lenguaje humano y se comunica por telepatía. Cuando Mew2 descubre que es resultado de un experimento de clonación, se indigna, mata a los científicos y destruye el laboratorio. Mew2 forma un ejército biodiverso de clones para dominar o destruir el mundo, pero aparece el Mew original, que trata de convencer a su clon que la violencia no resuelve nada. Guerreando, es herido el protagonista Ash quien se transforma en una estatua inerte... hasta que —inspirados por el tesón de su mascota— cada pokemon y su respectivo clon lloran y generan un hálito colectivo de vida que "resucita" a Ash. Conmovido, Mew2 da una oportunidad a los humanos y se retira con su ejército de clones, borrando de las mentes lo ocurrido. [...] Bueno, **la moraleja es simple: el poder del amor triunfa.***
>
> Revista Bioplanet. Biotecnología para sus negocios, 03-04/2003 : Editorial (Chile).

Comment: Moraleja fue lo primero que se me vino a la mente como sustantuvo concepto compacto y portador completo de la intención de comunicación requerida por "*take home message*" que de alguna manera hace equivalente la frase en inglés **the moral of [the/this] story is...** Misma que en efecto podría usarse intercambiablemente con la frase original...

Comment: Lo primero que me vino a la cabeza fue _quid_, que @Charlie menciona, pero a mí por sí sola esa palabra me suena rara; yo lo uso siempre en la frase "el quid de la cuestión".